# Need to center div inside parent vertically while keeping all div's fluid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, fluid-layout

I am having an issue centering a div with text in it vertically while keeping everything fluid. The text div's have photos next to them that change the container height upon browser size. I need the text to stay centered within its container when the section shrinks. Any advice would be awesome!
[Here is my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/patricksharer/vg312ktf/1/)

The sections I need help with are set up as follows, and the text within info is what needs to be centered vertically.

```
<section class="section">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-7 info-outer">
        <div class="info">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
          <p>Fusce tristique sem sem, nec hendrerit tellus tincidunt mollis. Sed dui risus, fringilla eu congue vitae, tempus sed erat. Cras et molestie ligula. Fusce molestie eros ac enim imperdiet, sit amet gravida mauris fermentum. Sed rutrum eros
            sed elit ultricies, consectetur tincidunt lorem aliquet. </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5 photo">
        <img src="css/images/3.jpg" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
  </section>
  <!-- /.section -->
```

Answer (score 2):

If you add this to .floor-plan-info, it will vertically align the content. (Going off of your JS fiddle)

`position: relative;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);`

This method is normally pretty reliable for vertically aligning content.